# Unable to download package in msys2 - fail to connect to mirror, server

Tags: c, msys2, pacman-package-manager

```
$ pacman -Syu
:: Synchronizing package databases...
 clangarm64.db failed to download
 mingw32.db failed to download
 mingw64.db failed to download
 ucrt64.db failed to download
 clang32.db failed to download
error: failed retrieving file 'ucrt64.db' from mirror.msys2.org : Failed to connect to mirror.msys2.org port 443 after 30 ms: Couldn't connect to server
error: failed retrieving file 'clang32.db' from mirror.msys2.org : Failed to connect to mirror.msys2.org port 443 after 29 ms: Couldn't connect to server
error: failed retrieving file 'clangarm64.db' from mirror.msys2.org : Failed to connect to mirror.msys2.org port 443 after 36 ms: Couldn't connect to server
warning: too many errors from mirror.msys2.org, skipping for the remainder of this transaction
error: failed retrieving file 'mingw32.db' from mirror.msys2.org : Failed to connect to mirror.msys2.org port 443 after 36 ms: Couldn't connect to server
```

I tried to reinstall but nothing changed, please help me!!

Comment: I have the same problem; apparently, some companies block outgoing connections to port 443